# List the users of a folder and their access in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, user-folders, read-write

How to find the list of users in any domain who have read/write/whatever access to a folder in windows 10.

Comment: Are we talking about local permissions, or permissions on a network share?

Comment: If that matters, then Networks share

Comment: Yes it does matter, because network shares usually hold security groups, and in order to find out who is a member of a security group, you need access to Active Directory Users and Groups, which means that you are either a domain administrator or have direct access to the Domain Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below script:

$project_folder = "full/path/to/directory"
get-acl $project_folder | %{ $_.Access  } | ft -property IdentityReference, AccessControlType, FileSystemRights

Additionally, you may try the [solution](https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/current-permission-analysis.html) to see who has which permissions on your shared folder

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. where I need to run that script ?